# How to get changed attributes without locale suffixes in Mobility gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobility

The documentation about [dirty tracking](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility#dirty-tracking) in the mobility gem states that:

> Mobility uses locale suffixes to indicate which locale has changed; dirty tracking is implemented this way to ensure that it is clear what has changed in which locale, avoiding any possible ambiguity.

So the result of `#changed` would look like this

```rb
post.changed
#=> ["title_en", "title_zh_cn", "body_en"]
```

However, I would like to get a simplified array of the attributes that were changed, without suffixes, like so:

```rb
#=> ["title", "body"]
```

How should I go about doing that other than manipulating the result of `#changed`?

Thanks,
Simon.

Comment: in the documentation it doesn't seems to be an option for this, why you don't want to work with this result and take out just the attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** (2019/10/24)

I realized it's actually a bit simpler, since the changes presumably happened in the current locale. In that case, you can simply strip the locale accessor from attributes (assuming any untranslated attributes don't have weird names with locale extensions on them):

```
post.changed.map { |attr| attr.gsub(/_#{Mobility.normalized_locale}$/, '') }
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

How about:

```
post.changed.map { |attr| attr.gsub /_([a-z]{2}(_[a-z]{2})?)/, ''}.uniq
#=> ["title", "body"]
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant "mobility-way" but that also works. Thanks!

Comment: I realized you don't really need the regex if you know the locale, added another way to do it.